# Minecraft | Spigot | Set Double or argument Decimal limit in command

Tags: java, double, minecraft, spigot

I am currently working on my own currency system and am now looking for a solution to limit the decimal places in the argument to solve this problem.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kJRH.png)

> "/command username
> 4.555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555565555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555551"

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if (sender instanceof Player) {
            Player player = (Player) sender;

            if (args.length == 0) {
                player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7/Bezahlen §8(§aSpieler§8) §8(§aBetrag§8)");
                player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Dein Kontostand: §a" + moneyapi.getMoney(player.getUniqueId()));
                return false;
            } else {
                Player target = Bukkit.getPlayer(args[0]);
                
                if (args.length == 1) {
                    player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7/Bezahlen §8(§aSpieler§8) §8(§aBetrag§8)");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (args.length == 2) {
                        if (isDouble(args[1])) {
                            if (Double.parseDouble(args[1]) >= 1) {
                                if (target != null) {
                                    if (target != player) {
                                        if (moneyapi.hasEnough(player.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1]))) {
                                            moneyapi.removeMoney(player.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
                                            moneyapi.addMoney(target.getUniqueId(), Double.parseDouble(args[1]));

                                            player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Bezahlt: §a" + target.getName().toString() + "§8(§c-" + args[1] + "§8)");
                                            target.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Erhalten: §c" + player.getName().toString() + "§8(§a+" + args[1] + "§8)");
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Du kannst dir kein Geld senden!");
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Dieser Spieler ist nicht online! " + "§8(§a" + args[0] + "§8)");
                                    return false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Bitte gebe einen gültigen Betrag ein!");
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            player.sendMessage(Main.prefix + "§7Bitte gebe einen gültigen Betrag ein!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            sender.sendMessage(Main.consoleblocker);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Could you guys possibly help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the amount of decimals on a double by using `BigDecimal.valueOf(value).scale() > 2` where `value` is the double your checking. (2 in this case is the amount of decimal places max, you can change this to whatever number)

Comment: What value do I enter to no longer have a decimal place? The value "0" or "-1" doesn't seem to help and I haven't found the right one yet, @ElmoPog

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to limit the decimal when showing the value.

1. **Number format**. This is good if you want to limit with minimal and maximal amount of char for integers and fractions. Example:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
```

Then, to show value, use: `nf.format(amount)`.

2. **String format**. Easiet way :

```
String.format("%.3f", amount);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tip. I have installed it on me and it works really well. However, I have not found a correct answer whether you can use this function with doubles, @elikill58

Comment: Both works with double, float of all value like that